# list-element is not found by beatiful soup even though it exists

Tags: python, html, dom, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

in my bs4-script, a li-element (XPATH: /html/body/div[1]/section/div/aside/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]) I want to crawl only contains an a-element. When I open the URL (https://www.kettenbertl.de/kettenschwerter-nach-maschinentyp/hersteller-mit-a/), inspecting the html with chrome shows another ul-element inside the li.

But when I crawl it with bs4, the li-element only contains the link-tag. I already read about bs4 not recognizing new elements created with JavaScript, but this does not seem to be the case here, I tried a fix for this and it still doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Mind showing us your code as a [mre]?

Comment: What information do you want to get from the page?

Comment: I can see the li(s) in the page source. Most likely you are using an xpath which becomes invalid with un-rendered content.

Comment: @baduker I wrote this question after I left my workspace, sorry, I can do it tomorrow if nothing works. But just capturing the whole html with bs4 and inspecting it does not show the ul-element, so I assumed it isn't the crawling-code's flaw.

Comment: @AndrejKesely The product data in the middle plus the path to get there (e.g. "Hersteller mit A | AEG | KS35 | Fuehrungsschienen-schwerter")

Comment: @QHarr I don't use XPATH, I use the find-methods etc. from bs4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get info about all products + their categories you can use next example (I used `multiprocessing.Pool` to speed things up):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing import Pool


url = "https://www.kettenbertl.de/kettenschwerter-nach-maschinentyp/hersteller-mit-a/"


def get_total_pages_and_api_url(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    url = soup.select_one("[data-listing-url]")["data-listing-url"]
    data = requests.get(url, params={"p": 1}).json()
    return data["totalCount"], url


def get_products(page):
    print(f"Getting page {page}")

    out = []
    data = requests.get(api_url, params={"p": page, "loadProducts": 1}).json()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data["listing"], "html.parser")

    titles = soup.select(".product--title")
    desc = soup.select(".product--description")
    prices = soup.select(".product--price")

    assert len(titles) == len(desc) == len(prices)

    for t, d, p in zip(titles, desc, prices):
        out.append(
            {
                "url": t["href"].split("?")[0],
                "title": t["title"],
                "description": d.get_text(strip=True),
                "price": p.get_text(strip=True).strip("*").strip(),
            }
        )

    return out


def get_category(info):
    print(f'Get category for {info["url"]}')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(info["url"]).content, "html.parser")

    info["category"] = " > ".join(
        i.get_text(strip=True) for i in soup.select(".breadcrumb--entry")
    )

    # maybe get other info about product here
    # ...

    return info


if __name__ == "__main__":
    total_pages, api_url = get_total_pages_and_api_url(url)

    all_data = []
    with Pool() as pool:
        for info in pool.imap_unordered(get_products, range(total_pages + 1)):
            all_data.extend(info)

        all_data = list(pool.imap_unordered(get_category, all_data))

    df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
    df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
    print(df.head().to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | url | title | description | price | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | https://www.kettenbertl.de/kettenschwerter-nach-maschinentyp/hersteller-mit-a/alko/bks-4245/saegeketten/754/saegekette-ersatzkette-fuer-motorsaege-alko-bks-42/45-schwert-35-cm-3/8-1-3 | Sägekette Ersatzkette für Motorsäge ALKO BKS 42/45 Schwert 35 cm 3/8 1,3 | Langlebige original Kettenbertl Halbmeißelkette in Spitzenqualität gute Schnittleistung besonders widerstandsfähig mehrmaliges schärfen möglich (Hand oder Maschine) robust und pflegeleicht 3/8 1,3 mm - Hobby 50 Treibglieder | 13,00 € | Ketten/Schwerter nach Maschinentyp > Hersteller mit A > ALKO > BKS 42/45 > Sägeketten |
| 1 | https://www.kettenbertl.de/kettenschwerter-nach-maschinentyp/hersteller-mit-a/alko/526-ac3107-16-38/saegeketten/755/saegekette-ersatzkette-fuer-motorsaege-alko-526-ac3107-16-38-schwert-35-cm-3/8-1-3 | Sägekette Ersatzkette für Motorsäge ALKO 526 (AC3107 16-38) Schwert 35 cm 3/8 1,3 | Langlebige original Kettenbertl Halbmeißelkette in Spitzenqualität gute Schnittleistung besonders widerstandsfähig mehrmaliges schärfen möglich (Hand oder Maschine) robust und pflegeleicht 3/8 1,3 mm - Hobby 49 Treibglieder | 12,70 € | Ketten/Schwerter nach Maschinentyp > Hersteller mit A > ALKO > 526 (AC3107 16-38) > Sägeketten |
| 2 | https://www.kettenbertl.de/kettenschwerter-nach-maschinentyp/hersteller-mit-a/alko/2300/saegeketten/644/saegekette-ersatzkette-fuer-motorsaege-alko-2300-schwert-30-cm-3/8-1-3 | Sägekette Ersatzkette für Motorsäge ALKO 2300 Schwert 30 cm 3/8 1,3 | Langlebige original Kettenbertl Halbmeißelkette in Spitzenqualität gute Schnittleistung besonders widerstandsfähig mehrmaliges schärfen möglich (Hand oder Maschine) robust und pflegeleicht 3/8 1,3 mm - Hobby 45 Treibglieder | 11,70 € | Ketten/Schwerter nach Maschinentyp > Hersteller mit A > ALKO > 2300 > Sägeketten |
| 3 | https://www.kettenbertl.de/kettenschwerter-nach-maschinentyp/hersteller-mit-a/alko/526-ac3107-16-38/saegeketten/751/saegekette-ersatzkette-fuer-motorsaege-alko-526-ac3107-16-38-schwert-35-cm-3/8-1-3 | Sägekette Ersatzkette für Motorsäge ALKO 526 (AC3107 16-38) Schwert 35 cm 3/8 1,3 | Langlebige original Kettenbertl Halbmeißelkette in Spitzenqualität gute Schnittleistung besonders widerstandsfähig mehrmaliges schärfen möglich (Hand oder Maschine) robust und pflegeleicht 3/8 1,3 mm - Hobby 50 Treibglieder | 13,00 € | Ketten/Schwerter nach Maschinentyp > Hersteller mit A > ALKO > 526 (AC3107 16-38) > Sägeketten |
| 4 | https://www.kettenbertl.de/kettenschwerter-nach-maschinentyp/hersteller-mit-a/alko/bks3535/saegeketten/753/saegekette-ersatzkette-fuer-motorsaege-alko-bks35/35-schwert-35-cm-3/8-1-3 | Sägekette Ersatzkette für Motorsäge ALKO BKS35/35 Schwert 35 cm 3/8 1,3 | Langlebige original Kettenbertl Halbmeißelkette in Spitzenqualität gute Schnittleistung besonders widerstandsfähig mehrmaliges schärfen möglich (Hand oder Maschine) robust und pflegeleicht 3/8 1,3 mm - Hobby 50 Treibglieder | 13,00 € | Ketten/Schwerter nach Maschinentyp > Hersteller mit A > ALKO > BKS35/35 > Sägeketten |

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a way easier approach than I did and I learned a lot from it